# How to check if an ArrayList of objects contains my object?

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist, contains

I have an `ArrayList` of objects. Some of these objects are of this class:

```
public class NewCompactSimilar
{
    public List<int> offsets;
    public List<String> words;
    public int pageID;

    public NewCompactSimilar()
    {
        offsets = new List<int>();
        words = new List<string>();          
    }
}
```

But the list can also contain objects of other classes.

I need to check if my `ArrayList` contains an object that is identical to my object.

So, how can I do that?

Comment: Why do use generic `List<T>` in your class. But keep your classes in non-generic `AraryList`?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (words.Contains(myObject))
```

ArrayList has a method called Contains which checks if the Object has the same Reference than the one you have. If you want to check if the value is the same, but a different Reference, you have to Code:

```
private bool GetEqual(String myString)
{
    foreach (String word in words)
    {
         if (word.Equals(myString))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I hope this is it :)

Answer (score 1):

With list being your `ArrayList` and item being the `NewCompactSimilar` you are searching for:

```
list.OfType<NewCompactSimilar>().
                FirstOrDefault(o => o.offsets == item.offsets &&
                o.words == item.words &&
                o.pageID == item.pageID);
```

To run a deep equality comparison, implement the following method:

```
public bool DeepEquals(NewCompactSimilar other)
{
    return offsets.SequenceEqual(other.offsets) &&
            words.SequenceEqual(other.words) &&
            pageID == other.pageID;
}
```

Then use the following LINQ chain:

```
list.OfType<NewCompactSimilar>().
                FirstOrDefault(o => o.DeepEquals(item));
```

Comment: Note that offset and words themselves are Lists, so would this work?

Comment: Also, I can't convert my ArrayLis to List, since it have multiple types of objects.